# What's a great way to store knives for me?

Tags: efficiency, storage, knives

My situation: I have accumulated high-quality purpose-made knives which are difficult to store due to several factors:

1. I have more than a few (23), and some (7) that I use quite often.
2. I want them to be handy and accessible.
3. Their size varies from small (16 cm) to large (40 cm).
4. I have no duplicates. (Well, there's an elderly one that I never use but keep for sentiment.)
5. Each one is for a different purpose, (i.e.: paring, bread, frozen foods, cook's knife, carving set, cake, etc.) so their proportions vary.
6. There are various wall racks and countertop containers available; but, I don't want them "out" and prefer to keep them in a drawer, somehow. (Edit: Drawer size is 30cm x 50cm x 10cm)
7. They are *sharp* and must be prevented from hitting each other or things that can dull or nick the blade edge.
8. I must store them safely.
9. Storage space is not unlimited.

The ideal solution would satisfy all my conditions. A great one will meet most of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My first thought comprises 3 elements:

- a dedicated kitchen drawer
- a non-skid mat
- 1 or 2 nylon hair combs

The first step is simple:  Cut the non-skid mat to fit the drawer.  Lay it in there.

The next step, involving the hair combs, is where it gets weird: Position the combs in the drawer, with the tines pointing at the ceiling, 6-8 inches from the front of the drawer, parallel with the front of the drawer. Then, place a knife in the drawer, pointing at the back of it, with its blade through the comb. The comb will keep it from falling over, left or right.

[image]

You can place other knives in parallel with the first knife, with all their handles aligned at the front of the drawer, and none of their blades touching each other.  When you need to take a knife out, the weight of the other knives should keep the comb from lifting up.

If you want to keep the blades from touching the non-skid pad you've spread out in the drawer, you could use 2 combs: one closer to the handles, and one a few inches farther down the blades.

You may want to keep the comb(s) upright more securely, so you aren't just relying on the friction of the tines against the blades. Supports shouldn't be too hard to dream up:

- a couple of L-braces
- another comb perpendicular to the first comb, and you slide the first comb in between the teeth of the second comb
- just hot-glue it to the side of the drawer

This solution doesn't address the other gadgets you mention in point 5 of your question.

Comment: Yes. If I use NYLON combs, they are soft enough so they won't hurt the blade edge even if I place the edges down and the blades rest on them. NICE HACK (nice sketch, too.)

Comment: @Stan I'd been picturing nylon combs; I just forgot to clarify that in my answer. I'll add it!

Comment: The under pad you suggest should have lines or some pattern to make it easier to align the knives when putting them away to avoid hitting each other.

Comment: @Stan Oo, that's smart! I just included it to keep the knives from sliding around when you open / close the drawer.

Answer (score 5):

A knife block? - is there any reason why you don't want this option?

[image: knife block drawer]

Comment: not all knife blocks are created equally. THINK OUTSIDE OF THE BOX

Comment: https://www.google.ca/search?q=flat+knife+block&tbm=isch&imgil=hCMSfSAMgdw2jM%253A%253Boh6vgpbb5-J9pM%253Bhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.amazon.com%25252Fdp%25252FB01DG45HOU&source=iu&pf=m&fir=hCMSfSAMgdw2jM%253A%252Coh6vgpbb5-J9pM%252C_&usg=__6vqV3bJyNOYJw2V9fz88DxSe2pw%3D&biw=1792&bih=990&ved=0ahUKEwiV4--Tg6jWAhUkyoMKHSmwDEwQyjcIUQ&ei=Rze8WdWjE6SUjwSp4LLgBA#imgrc=hCMSfSAMgdw2jM:

Comment: I am using a similar "block" for a few of them. My collection appears to have been assembled by taking one knife from 23 different matched sets. Thanx for the link to google. A knife block uses significant amounts of drawer real estate.

Comment: Knife blocks can be stacked. Your drawer is high enough to place a small knife block on top of a larger one. Being made of wood, a knife block can be easily cut to size. Or you can make your own (you need a router or an adjustable-depth table saw to do that efficiently).

Comment: @Hobbes, Easily cut? I've used a router once in my life and I'm lucky I have all my fingers to add this comment. StevenXavier commented a google link (above) with enough knife blocks to build a house. I get your point though.

Comment: To cut a store-bought knife block to size, any saw will do. That's the easy part. Using a router to build your own knife block is a bit more advanced woodworking, yes.

Comment: My "problem" with the knife block is disappointment that the solution is always buy more things. See #6. My "problem" with a "Google" search is the result may or may not be applicable or practical for me. I know what it is and how to do one. I came here for a… lifehacks "out-of-the-box" answer for my "in-the-drawer" issue.

Answer (score 4):

So I don't have *that* many knives, but I have a similar problem. I ended up making my own knife sheaths from old soda/cereal/cake flour/etc boxes. I used a different one for each knife so quickly locate the knife I am looking for in a drawer full of kitchen utensils.

I used the instructions I found [here](http://italianmeddiet.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Kitchen-Knife-Sheath.pdf).

And created sheaths that look like this.

[image: My sheaths]

There is the downside that this leaves them loose in the drawer, but it protects them & makes it easy to find the one I am looking for. (Bread Knife? that's the one with the Mountain Dew logo. Santoku? Captain Crunch.) The upside is that these are made out of what would otherwise be garbage and they are super easy to replace.

If you wanted to take this a step further you could cut open the tops of these sheaths and then glue them together separated by some leftover packing styrofoam. However I did try that, and it didn't work as well as I wanted due to the fact that my knife lengths vary quite a bit. (5-12+ inches). And it ended up taking more drawer room than I wanted.

Comment: Hi nbppp2, Welcome to lifehacks.stackexchange. Yes, I agree. This is a good idea that satisfies many of the points I listed. I like the possibility of matching the sheath logo with the knife purpose - an aesthetic challenge. This is, in fact, one of the solutions I use for several knives. I even tried to use a blank licence plate (unbreakable polyethylene) but that stuff came up short like your second "refinement."

Answer (score 2):

Buy a pack of toothpicks. Place them in a container something [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuQf4.jpg)

Or if you are willing to work harder, try making this DIY wooden arrangement. Pretty safe and nice to look at!!

[image]

Comment: I don't get the toothpick idea. The cupboard door is pretty good placement for a "block" for a few of them, too. That's "outside the box" thinking that @StevenXavier mentioned. Only 20 more to go!

Comment: @Stan The toothpick idea is for accessibility. If you wish to keep them handy, outside your drawer and want the knives to not touch each other. Could be kept on a table/slab as per use

Comment: Okay, I found the link to the "pack of toothpicks" idea—finally. If I understand you, you're suggesting that concept; but, unlike the photo which shows knives on a counter-top, I could make a shorter drawer-version—a tray-like holder with enough toothpicks vertically to hold my knives horizontal to fit inside a drawer. That's a lot of loose toothpicks ! ! !

Comment: Okay (part 2) I tried the idea with toothpicks - round and flat. I got a few boxes of each. It seems that the concept doesn't scale-down or scale-wide very well. The length of the vertical "pins" must be longer than the width of the holder for them or they "wander" and collapse. Now I know how they work and don't.

Comment: @Stan Toothpick idea is more suited for (smaller) knives of similar length. I guess you should try this wooden holder idea. Should save you much needed space, while being accessible and not damaging for the blades. Also, I'm glad that you tried it, and then posted a review for everyone to see. Appreciate that! :)

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion to preserve the blade edge would be as follows:

- Just like the one shown below, try to make some CD cover for your knife set. It may take some time for you to rearrange them after your use but it will save your knife blades sharpness from clinging to each other as well your hand when you reach out to it in the drawer.
  [image]
- Just like the one shown below, keep a beautiful pot of sand as an art in your kitchen work area. As you get time, you can beautifully arrange you knives by inserting them into the sand in it(It can be on the basis of their size). In times of urgency, you can easily take it out and easily put them inside without clinging to each other. Moreover, refined sand(very fine) is good for the knife as it can only increase your blades sharpness. Also, please take care that soil does not get wet at any cost as it can decay your blades too. 
  [image]

Comment: @Stan Thanks, have added, they were already there as hyperlinks on this.

Comment: Both points are good ones. Cases that hold more than a few are less desirable as I have to remove all of them (in the case) from storage, open the case, remove the knife, put the case somewhere each time I use one. A case would work for the pieces of my carving set; but, I would like the rest to be handy without using my counter top to store them.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about gluing a magnetic strip to the inside of your draw?
It would keep the knives relatively still and therefore prevent them losing their sharp edges and won't take over the draw.

ANOTHER OPTION

Again this option uses a magnet.

You could have a strong magnet glued to a wall or something which your blades could stick too.

Comment: They don't move around much. The problem is there is a big variety of various sizes and handle shapes to store.

Comment: Help me. I don't understand. If I put magnets (or a strip) inside; one knife would fit against the front, and one each along both sides. That's three of the twenty-three left to put away. What am I missing? Where do they go?You're right about the wall; but, my knives are not at all attractive so I'd have to think hard about displaying them. If I went to visit someone and their wall was full of knives, …

Comment: what? You are way over complicating things. Lay them down all the same way so the tips of each blade sits on the magnet. That will prevent your knives banging into each other. When I was a chef that's what I had.

Comment: Your answer is not clear. Magnets or a magnetic strip tells me nothing about how to use "magnets" in a drawer. Do you have a picture, or a diagram, since you don't give any detail. Your idea or lifehack may be good but your answer is very low quality. Jus' sayin' - I tried to get you to explain in my above two comments; but, you tell me how to put a knife on a magnet instead of where to put the magnets.

Comment: Well you know it's not rocket science? You glue a magnetic strip to the bottom of the draw. I thought that was obvious lol

Comment: You're right. I was too stoopid to get it. I was hoping for a clever life hack. Your answer was a simple knife rack. The key word missing in your answer was "bottom." Sometimes the obvious escapes us. That's why detailed answers are better for understanding. Did you notice my first comment? In addition, I don't have enough room to store them all flat. My overall response is, "meh."

Comment: I'm sure ill survive your indifference...

Comment: I have a confession. I already use magnets; but, not as you suggested. I use heavy gauge magnetic sheets folded lengthwise to make a "sheath" that opens like a wallet. I made two from an A4 size sheet.